# jQuery dislplay none - show/hide div's lagging

Tags: jquery, html, css

He there Developers ;)

The issue is that i get a lag when want to hide a div and show a div by clicking a button.
Is there a better way to fix it without lagging?

```
$("#toggle-f").click(function(){
    if ($("#toggle-finder").css("display") == "none") {

        $("#toggle-safari").fadeOut();
        $("#toggle-voorkeuren").fadeOut();
        $("#toggle-mappen").fadeOut();
        $("#toggle-finder").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#toggle-finder").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: provide the rest of your html code

Comment: [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) have a default duration of 400ms, change it to a shorter time - e.g. `fadeOut(200)`.

Comment: I don't think "lag" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: You're not showing or hiding, that would be `show()` and `hide()`, you're fading, hence the names `fadeOut()` etc.

Comment: It would be better to use `if (!$('#toggle-finder').is(':visible')) {`, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

can you use .hide() and .show() instead of .fade? if that's what you are referring to lag

```
 $("#toggle-f").click(function(){
        if ($("#toggle-finder").css("display") == "none") {

            $("#toggle-safari").hide(); $("#toggle-voorkeuren").hide();
            $("#toggle-mappen").hide(); $("#toggle-finder").show();
        } else {
            $("#toggle-finder").hide();
        }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really going to help your performance much, but it's a very slightly more efficient. "lag" usually means your hardware can't handle the software.. turn off other programs and stuff.

```
$("#toggle-f").click(function() {
  if($("#toggle-finder").is(":visible")){
    $("#toggle-safari, "+
    "#toggle-voorkeuren, "+
    "#toggle-mappen, "+
    "#toggle-finder").fadeOut();
  } else {
    $("#toggle-finder").fadeOut();
  }
});
```